# How can I recreate the camera used in Swordigo game?

Tags: unity, camera

What sort of camera does the Android game (2.5D) Swordigo uses? Is it an orthogrpahic camera? I think it is an angled orthographic projection.

How can I recreate that sort of camera in Unity?

[image: example]

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: yes, I am able to quite match the look by using an angled orthographic camera in unity, needed validation

Comment: If you were able to match the look already, why do you need additional validation? If your solution works for your needs, it works for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a perspective camera looking at the scene from the side. You can tell it's perspective because it shows the platforms from a slightly different angle depending on their position. The camera appears to be angled a slight bit downwards to better show off the top surfaces of the platforms.

An orthographic camera would render all plaforms in the exact same perspective (assuming they are all axis-aligned)

Comment: It also probably has a narrow field of view. I'd say close to 30 or 40 degrees instead of the usual 60, which makes things look flatter.